# Function $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ which is $C^2$ but not $C^3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'd like to find an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ which is $C^2$ but not $C^3$. I am not really sure how to find such an example.

 I have $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y),f_3(x,y))$ and I need the second derivative not to be continuous, for instance.

 The first derivative w.r.t $x$ is $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\bigg( \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(x,y),\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x}(x,y) \bigg)$$
and the second is given by
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\bigg( \frac{\partial^2 f_1}{\partial x^2}(x,y),\frac{\partial^2 f_2}{\partial^2 x}(x,y),\frac{\partial^2 f_3}{\partial^2 x}(x,y) \bigg).$$

Comment: Often in this type of problem, it's easier to start with a function that is not continuous or not differentiable and integrate that function an appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$The function $g$ is continuous (actually, it is differentiable, although not a $C^1$ function). Take $h\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that $h''=g$. Finally, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^3\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\bigl(h(x),0,0\bigr).\end{array}$$Then $f$ is a $C^2$ function, but it's not $C^3$.